# Error in publishing in Tomcat 6 in eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat6, eclipse-juno

I am getting the following error while starting the Tomcat 6 server. I have configured JDK as run time.

```
Publishing failed
Could not create directory \\<user directory>\Desktop\'E:\test\Tomcat\webapps\tmywebproj.
```

The path

**\Desktop\'E:\test\Tomcat\webapps\tmywebproj** is invalid path.

**My tomcat installation is there in E: drive.**

**But the message corresponds to an invalid path.**

**EDIT**

```
My Tomcat installation directory: E:\test\Tomcat
My workspace: E:\test\workspace
```

Please suggest me how to correct this error.

I tried deleting and adding the server again, and restarting the eclipse. But none of them worked.

**Edit**

```
Deploy Path:  E:\test\Tomcat\webapps

Server Path:  E:\test\Tomcat
```

Tomcat Screen shot
[image]

Comment: @NoobUnChained. Thanks for replying. I have edited the question. Please suggest.

Comment: What's in your Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Tomcat -> Tomcat home?

Comment: where is your eclipse installed? looks like instead of taking it as Absolute path its taking it as relative path from desktop.

Comment: ca you provide your tomcat's overview screen(double click on server name)?

Comment: @rahulmaindargi. Thank you for replying. My installation path of eclipse is C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\eclipse.exe. Sorry for delay :)

Comment: @jubinPatel. Thanks for replying. I have added the screen shot. Please  suggest.

Comment: change deploy path set only "webapps" and try again.

Comment: @jubinPatel.. Thank you very much..It worked like a charm. I am struggling with this since 3 days. Simple small change did the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your deploy path its incorrect.

click on link(which is upper to deploy path)

[image]

OR

set only "webapps" and try again.(Some times your application deploy on "wtpwebapps" folder in tomcat so first conform that and then select).

Answer (score -1):

You have control if your Runtime Environment have correct path?
You can see on Windows>Preferences>Server>Runtime_Environment now you can insert (on Add) Apache with correct directory or control if directory is correct.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But the path of tomcat directory is correct only.